# SQL: Unable to join multiple select statements

Tags: sql

I have a a table as below:

| SourceCustomerId | BusinessDate | HasTaxBenifit | HasCollateral | HasLoan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BS:100037 | 2016-12-23 | No | No | Yes |
| BS:100056 | 2018-01-13 | No | Yes | No |
| BS:100037 | 2011-06-03 | No | Yes | Yes |
| BS:100056 | 2019-10-14 | Yes | No | No |
| BS:100022 | 2014-09-17 | Yes | No | Yes |
| BS:100037 | 2013-07-18 | Yes | Yes | No |
| BS:100056 | 2016-03-19 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| BS:100022 | 2015-04-20 | Yes | No | No |
| BS:100022 | 2017-08-14 | No | Yes | No |
| BS:100022 | 2012-11-23 | No | Yes | No |

And the output that I am expecting is

| BinaryTaxBenefit | BinaryLoan | BinaryCollateral | diff_BinaryTaxBenefit | diff_BinaryLoan | diff_BinaryCollateral |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

To obtain this output, We need to follow three steps:

1. Partition the data by SourceCustomerID and then order the data by Source customer ID and Business Date
2. Create other columns BinaryTaxBenefit, BinaryLoan,   BinaryCollateral The logic is every column has  a binary equivalent and they will be having a value of 0 if the columns are having a value 'No'
3. Last and most difficult part subtract(BinaryColumn's only) the rows.  But the subtraction must be within the group only.
   So the first value difference is always NULL and the rest difference

I am able to write separate SQL queries for Step1 and Step2 :

Step1: Partition Data by SourceCustomerID and then order the data by Source customer ID and Business Date:

```
    SELECT 
        SourceCustomerId,
        BusinessDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SourceCustomerId ORDER BY SourceCustomerId, BusinessDate ASC) RowNumber,
        HasTaxBenifit,
        HasLoan,
        HasCollateral
    from personDetail pd
```

from personDetail pd

Step2: Create other columns BinaryTaxBenefit, BinaryLoan,   BinaryCollateral:

```
    select * ,
           (case when HasTaxBenifit = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as BinaryTaxBenefit,
           (case when HasLoan = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as BinaryLoan,
           (case when HasCollateral = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as BinaryCollateral
    from personDetail pd
```

**How to I club step1 and Step2 into a single SQL Query?**

Step3: Last and most difficult part subtract(Binary Column's only) the rows:

**Here it is subtract all the rows without considering the gorup, not sure how to fix this**

```
    with v as (
      select RowNumber, BinaryTaxBenefit, BinaryLoan, BinaryCollateral from personDetailTrial
    )
    select
      RowNumber,BinaryTaxBenefit, BinaryLoan, BinaryCollateral,
      BinaryTaxBenefit - lag(BinaryTaxBenefit, 1) over(order by RowNumber) as diff_BinaryTaxBenefit,
      BinaryLoan - lag(BinaryLoan, 1) over(order by RowNumber) as diff_BinaryLoan,
      BinaryCollateral - lag(BinaryCollateral, 1) over(order by RowNumber) as diff_BinaryCollateral
    from v
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understood, you can use CROSS APLY,

https://www.sqlshack.com/es/la-diferencia-entre-cross-apply-y-outer-apply-en-sql-server/